# Convert a letter in string to different letters with multiple output

Tags: python, python-2.7, bioinformatics, python-itertools

So I have a DNA sequence

`DNA = "TANNNT"`

`where N = ["A", "G", "C", "T"]`

I want to have all possible output of `TAAAAT, TAAAGT, TAAACT, TAAATT.....` and so on.

Right now from online I found solution of permutations where I can do 
`perms = [''.join(p) for p in permutations(N, 3)]`
then just iterate my DNA sequence as 
`TA + perms + T`

but I wonder if there is easier way to do this, because I have a lot more DNA sequences and make take a lot more time to hard code it.

**Edit:**

The hard code part will be as in I would have to state

```
N1 = [''.join(p) for p in permutations(N, 1)]
N2 = [''.join(p) for p in permutations(N, 2)]
N3 = [''.join(p) for p in permutations(N, 3)]
```

then do for i in N3:

```
key = "TA" + N3[i] + "T"
```

Since my sequence is quite long, I don't want count how many consecutive N I have in the sequence and want to see if there is better way to do this.

Comment: What part of this is hard coded that you would like to avoid?

Comment: I put this on edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your permutation results to format a string like:

**Code:**

```
import itertools as it
import re

def convert_sequence(base_string, target_letter, perms):
    REGEX = re.compile('(%s+)' % target_letter)
    match = REGEX.search(base_string).group(0)
    pattern = REGEX.sub('%s', base_string)
    return [pattern % ''.join(p) for p in it.permutations(perms, len(match))]
```

**Test Code:**

```
print(convert_sequence('TANNNT', 'N', ['A', 'G', 'C', 'T']))
```

**Results:**

```
['TAAGCT', 'TAAGTT', 'TAACGT', 'TAACTT', 'TAATGT', 
 'TAATCT', 'TAGACT', 'TAGATT', 'TAGCAT', 'TAGCTT', 
 'TAGTAT', 'TAGTCT', 'TACAGT', 'TACATT', 'TACGAT', 
 'TACGTT', 'TACTAT', 'TACTGT', 'TATAGT', 'TATACT', 
 'TATGAT', 'TATGCT', 'TATCAT', 'TATCGT']
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually help. I keep forgetting to use regular expression as I am not really familiar with unix yet